# how to print an array as a matrix in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, printing

so I´m trying to print this 2d array as a matrix and it´s not working. any hints? no matter what i change i cant get to print an all 0 3x3 matrix

```
    int main()
        {
        int i, j, m, n, primeira;
        int matrix[10][20];

        printf("Enter number of rows : ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        printf("Enter number of columns : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        /* first input */
        printf("1 ou 0");
            scanf("%d", &primeira);
        if (primeira = 0) {
        matrix [0][0]=0;
matrix [0][1]=0;
matrix [1][0]=0;
matrix [1][1]=0;}




    /* Display the matrix */
    {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You obviously need some sort of loop. Have you actually attempted to code in a loop? Also, please format your code properly and provide code that has your best attempt and at least compiles.

Comment: so i cant just print an array?

Comment: Remember the difference between assignment with`=` and comparison for equality with `==`

Comment: And you also only initialize four of the 200 elements of `matrix`. Even if you change it to a 3 by 3 matrix, that will leave five elements uninitialized. Or rather, with the current assignment instead of comparison, you don't initialize *any* elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a nested loop to display the matrix. If you want to display a 3x3 matrix you can run something like this.

```
  int matrix[3][3] = { 0 };

  /* Display the matrix */
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf ("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
     }
     printf ("\n");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
```

The variables: `i` and `j` are not initialized!

Suggest:

```
for( int i =0; i<10; i++ ) 
{ 
    for( int j=0; j<20; j++ ) 
    { 
        printf( "%d ", matrix[i][j] );
    }
    puts( "" ); 
}
```

as that will print all the elements of the matrix and move to a new line after printing each row of the matrix.